# How to prove the formula for two dots contraction of two tensors

Tags: tensors

there is a formula $${\bf{T}} \cdot  \cdot \,{\bf{E}} = {T_{ij}}{E_{ji}} = tr({\bf{TE}})$$
I`m trying to prove it$$\eqalign{
  & {T_{ij}}{E_{ji}} = \left( {{{{\bf{\hat e}}}_i} \cdot {\bf{T}}{{{\bf{\hat e}}}_j}} \right)\left( {{{{\bf{\hat e}}}_j} \cdot {\bf{E}}{{{\bf{\hat e}}}_i}} \right) = \left( {{{{\bf{\hat e}}}_i} \cdot {\bf{T}}{{{\bf{\hat e}}}_j}} \right){{{\bf{\hat e}}}_j} \cdot {\bf{E}}{{{\bf{\hat e}}}_i} = {{{\bf{\hat e}}}_i} \cdot \underbrace {{{{\bf{\hat e}}}_j} \otimes {\bf{T}}{{{\bf{\hat e}}}_j} \cdot {\bf{E}}}_A{{{\bf{\hat e}}}_i} = {A_{ii}} = tr({\bf{A}})  \cr 
  & {\bf{A}} = {{{\bf{\hat e}}}_j} \otimes {\bf{T}}{{{\bf{\hat e}}}_j} \cdot {\bf{E}} = {{\bf{T}}^T}{\bf{E}} \cr} $$
Where is my mistake?Please help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**EDIT:** The question was about the coordinate formula for the trace of a product of two matrices.

The product of two matrices is given by $$(AB)_{ik} = \sum_{j} A_{ij}B_{jk}$$ So their trace is the sum of entries like the above when $i=k$, or: $$tr(AB) = \sum_{i,j} A_{ij}B_{ji}$$

---

**Do I understand your question correctly?** I think what you are saying is that you got $tr(T^TE)$, but you were expecting to get $tr(TE)$. If this is the case, make sure you inspect the definition of the double dot product from whatever reference you are using carefully, and also inspect what *type* of tensor $T,E$ are in your problem.

---

**Beware: There are two definitions/conventions for the double dot product.** According to wikipedia , this seems to be a common problem

> "There are two ways to define the double dot product, one must be careful when deciding which convention to use." Wikipedia, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dyadics#Product_of_dyadic_and_dyadic

The two formulas are

1. $ab:cd = (a\cdot d)(b\cdot c)$
2. $ab:cd = (a\cdot c)(b\cdot d)$

and can be found in the chart at the link above. The difference is in *transposing* $c$ and $d$, so you can see how this is the same issue as you are having.

Basically,

- if you start with two tensors $T_1,T_2$ both of type $(m,n)$ for $m\neq n$ then $T_1T_2$ doesn't make sense (you can't multiply matrices if the columns and rows don't match in the middle). $T_1^TT_2$ *does* make sense though.
- On the other hand, if $T_1$ is of type $(m,n)$ and $T_2$ is of type $(n,m)$ then $T_1T_2$ is the right expression.

In the case that $n=m$ everything is completely ambiguous, and the definitions do not agree - so you must be careful to be clear on the definition/convention chosen in your context!

---

Here are the two definitions.

> **Definition 1.** Let $T_1 \in V^*\otimes W$ and $T_2\in V\otimes W^*$ be tensors of opposite type. Then there is a tensor $T_1: T_2 \in V^*$ given by contraction and equal to $T_1:T_2 = tr(V\overset{T_2}\to W \overset{T_1}\to V) = tr(T_1T_2)$.

or,

> **Definition 2.** Let $T_1, T_2 \in V^*\otimes W$ be two tensors of the same type, then there is a tensor $T_1:T_2$ given by contraction and equal to $T_1:T_2 = tr(V\overset{T_2}\to W \overset{T_1^T}\to V) = tr(T_1^TT_2)$.

You may note that in the special case that $V = W$, again everything is ambiguous and you need to carefully check which definition has been made.

---

**Checking the formula.** I suppose if your asking specifically about tensor *contraction*, then definition 1 is probably the right definition. In this case there is an identity/definition (see Wikipedia)

$$ab:cd = (a\cdot d)(b\cdot c)$$

which you can apply:

\begin{align}
T:E &=
(\sum T_{ij}e_i^*\otimes e_j):(\sum E_{kl}e_k^*\otimes e_\ell)\\
&= \sum T_{ij}E_{kl} (e_i\cdot e_\ell)(e_j\cdot e_k)\\
&= \sum T_{ij}E_{ji}\\
&= tr(TE).
\end{align}

---

**Mistakes in your work.** It looks like you have sought to do something similar to the above. I can't really understand what you mean in your definition of $A$. You are taking the dot product of two tensors, $e_j\otimes Te_j$ and $E$? I cannot follow this step.

Comment: Thank you, you understood me correctly, forget about designations : or **, the main question is how to prove that TijEji=tr(TE)

Comment: @SergeyFomin Oh I see - this is a much simpler question to answer.

Comment: Thank you very much Ben, it is so easy. It's also interesting: What's wrong in my derivation?